# Background-aware text color

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive site that has a dynamically sized background image that has some dark and light areas. In browser the font colors are tuned to have nice contrast over the color of the background image.

Unfortunately in the responsive (mobile) design some text is layered over darker parts of the re-sized background image and the text can be very difficult to read. Does anyone know of a jQuery plugin or technique where the text can be made aware of the background behind it and change style/color accordingly?

Comment: why not change color of text according to css media query for example?

Comment: Nice topic, I am hoping for some creative answers - maybe a canvas solution for calculating the (sumerized) hex of the pixels behind the text?

Comment: Some sort of text shadowing or outline might solve your problem on larger text. Otherwise I'd go with a opace background

Answer (score 3):

you can use text-shadow to mark the edge of your text.

```
body {
/* your rules */
color: rgba(0 , 0, 0, 0.8 ); /* just a guess that it might be black;*/
text-shadow: 
    0 0 1px gold, 
    0 0 3px white; /* choose how many and which colors */
}
```

That is the idea

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking would basically entail this:

- assigning each word in the text to be wrapped with `<span>`
- use % position from top/left to get where in the picture it is, and dynamically assign color to spans that fall in that area.

For lack of a better word, **DON'T**. It's ridiculous, and way too much overhead to rationalize.

Why not just give a semi-transparent background to the container for the text, so that it stands out more?

```
.Container {
     background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

This provides a light tint for the text to pop against the image, while still letting the whole image show on the page.

The text-shadow solution is a good idea as well, but just a heads up that it won't work on IE9-. My solution would work on IE9, but not on IE8-, which doesn't mean its better but just something to keep in mind.